# POS payform in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I developed a Point of Sale system. I am having trouble with payform. I have the code for searching by barcode and name of product but I don't understand how to create a receipt database.

Here is my code for barcodes:

```
konekcija = New MySqlConnection
    konekcija.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=baza;port=3307"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bazaDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bajndsors As New BindingSource

    Try
        konekcija.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from baza.artikli where kod like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(bazaDataSet)
        bajndsors.DataSource = bazaDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bajndsors
        SDA.Update(bazaDataSet)
        konekcija.Close()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = bajndsors
        With DataGridView1
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "ид"
            .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Код"
            .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Назив на артикал"
            .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Набавна цена"
            .Columns(4).HeaderCell.Value = "Цена со ДДВ"
            .Columns(5).HeaderCell.Value = "Данок"
            .Columns(6).HeaderCell.Value = "Количина"
            .Columns(7).HeaderCell.Value = "Опис"
            .Columns(8).HeaderCell.Value = "Опис 2"
            .Columns(9).HeaderCell.Value = "Македонски Производ"
            .Columns(10).HeaderCell.Value = "Профит"
            .Columns(11).HeaderCell.Value = "Производител"
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        konekcija.Dispose()
    End Try
```

It is similar for the search by names.

Comment: What is the actual problem? I'm not following. Side note, you should use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings together.

Comment: A receipt is basically a report of the transactions for a particular customer over a specific time frame.  One thing that might make it easier is to assign a receipt ID to the transaction record.

Comment: If barcodes are unique, why would you use `LIKE` in the query?

Answer (score -1):

Kontaktiraj me brat imam nesto da te prasam vidi kaj mene na profil vo opis